# Asynchronously Run Console Output and GUI in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, console

I am working on building a GUI around a console application. I would like to be able to click a button to run the console app and show the console output inside of the GUI itself. How might I accomplish this? I am working in Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also try [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html). It provides a Qt interface to launching external processes, reading their I/O and waiting, or not, on their completion.

For your purpose, it sounds like you want the process to run asynchronously, so code might look like :

myprocessstarter.h :

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>


class MyProcessStarter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyProcessStarter() : QObject() {};
    void StartProcess();
private slots:
    void readStandardOutput();
private:
    QProcess *myProcess;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "myprocessstarter.h"

void MyProcessStarter::StartProcess()
{
    QString program = "dir";
    QStringList arguments;
    // Add any arguments you want to be passed

    myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readStandardOutput()));
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);
}

void MyProcessStarter::readStandardOutput()
{
    QByteArray processOutput;
    processOutput = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();

    qDebug() << "Output was " << QString(processOutput);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyProcessStarter s;
    s.StartProcess();
}
```

Comment: I receive the following error when I try your code: 
/main.cpp:99: error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function

Comment: @THE DOCTOR: You must put the code in a QObject, e.g. the widget displaying the output. readStandardOutput must be a slot.

Comment: The Doctor : I redid the sample to make it actually compile for you. The QProcess uses the Qt Signal/Slot mechanism to connect data from the process back to your code. If unfamiliar you can read about it [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: @docsteer - Thank you, it seems I'm starting to get on the right track here. I am now trying to pass in an argument with the path to a configuration file which my program uses. If I try running it from a terminal window, everything is fine. However, when I run it from the Qt Creator it doesn't read my config file. I'm using your code as is with the following line to pass in my argument: arguments << " -f /home/THEDOCTOR/Desktop/rtp/RTPgui-build-desktop/RTPConfig.config";

Comment: @THE DOCTOR : Hmm, sorry I can't help you much there as I'm on Win32 and don't use Qt Creator much. Perhaps you could replace your program path with that of an "echo" type program that will echo back the command line, to see if the arguments are getting mangled for some reason.

Comment: I just figured out the problem. In case anyone else runs into a similar issue and comes across this post...I needed to separate the switch in my argument from the path I was specifying with an additional bitwise operator. For example: arguments << "-f" << "/home/THEDOCTOR/configFile.config"; Thanks again docsteer. Your QProcess example helped me get this working.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do something similar in one of my applications. I redirected all output from the standard stream (cout) to my console window. To periodically read out the stream contents I use a timer loop. Works fine for me.

StdRedirector.cpp

```
#include "StdRedirector.h"

QMutex coutMutex;

void outcallback(const char* ptr, std::streamsize count, void* bufferString)
{
    string *b = (string *) bufferString;    
    string t;

    for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (ptr[i] == '\n')
        {
            t = t + "\n";
        } else {
            t = t + ptr[i];
        }
    }       

    coutMutex.lock();
    *b = *b + t;
    coutMutex.unlock();
}

void ConsoleWindow::updateTimer(void)
{   
    coutMutex.lock();
    if (bufferString.size() > 0)
    {
        consoleBox->insertPlainText(QString(bufferString.c_str()));
        bufferString.clear();

        QScrollBar *sb = consoleBox->verticalScrollBar();
        sb->setValue(sb->maximum());        
    }
    coutMutex.unlock();
}

ConsoleWindow::ConsoleWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    consoleBox = new QTextEdit(this);
    consoleBox->setReadOnly(true);

    stdRedirector = new StdRedirector<>(std::cout, outcallback, &bufferString);

    QVBoxLayout *vb = new QVBoxLayout();
    vb->addWidget(consoleBox);
    vb->setMargin(0);
    vb->setSpacing(0);  

    setLayout(vb);

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateTimer()));
    timer->start(100);
}

ConsoleWindow::~ConsoleWindow()
{
    delete stdRedirector;
}
```

StdRedirector.h

```
#ifndef STD_REDIRECTOR
#define STD_REDIRECTOR

#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QString>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QTimer.h>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QScrollBar>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class Elem = char, class Tr = std::char_traits<Elem>>

class StdRedirector : public std::basic_streambuf<Elem, Tr>
{
    typedef void (*pfncb) ( const Elem*, std::streamsize _Count, void* pUsrData );

    public:
        StdRedirector(std::ostream& a_Stream, pfncb a_Cb, void* a_pUsrData) :
            m_Stream(a_Stream),
            m_pCbFunc(a_Cb),
            m_pUserData(a_pUsrData)
        {
            m_pBuf = m_Stream.rdbuf(this);
        }

        ~StdRedirector()
        {
            m_Stream.rdbuf(m_pBuf);
        }

        std::streamsize xsputn(const Elem* _Ptr, std::streamsize _Count)
        {
            m_pCbFunc(_Ptr, _Count, m_pUserData);
            return _Count;
        }

        typename Tr::int_type overflow(typename Tr::int_type v)
        {
            Elem ch = Tr::to_char_type(v);
            m_pCbFunc(&ch, 1, m_pUserData);
            return Tr::not_eof(v);
        }

    protected:
        std::basic_ostream<Elem, Tr>& m_Stream;
        std::streambuf* m_pBuf;
        pfncb m_pCbFunc;
        void* m_pUserData;
};

class ConsoleWindow : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

    public:
        ConsoleWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~ConsoleWindow();

    public slots:
        void updateTimer(void);

    public:
        QTextEdit *consoleBox;
        StdRedirector<> *stdRedirector;
        string bufferString;
};

#endif
```

The StdRedirector class is based on code from this forum post: http://www.qtforum.org/article/24554/displaying-std-cout-in-a-text-box.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) function, it might do what you need.

Then you could pass the `FILE *` to a [`QTextStream`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextstream.html#QTextStream-3) and work in Qt style with it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, rather than showing stdout in GUI, having own console output, which essentially means all messages you want to show to users you are sending to your own output.

This way you can have debug messages and such still available from console, wtih potential errors with connections and whatever that can happen and have fully controlled console output in GUI application. Of course this output can also be outputted to stdout so it is visible in console, but it also allows you to append a prefixs like WARNING LOG NOTICE NO_THIS_WENT_WRONG or whatever you want to show to users as your console entry.